# Rsyslog forward log with space in path or name

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog

How would one go about forwarding a log file with a space in the filename or path using Rsyslog?

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application\ Support/Plex\ Media\ Server/Logs/*
$InputFileTag plex
$InputFileStateFile stat-plex
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local3
$InputRunFileMonitor
local3.* @@10.0.0.5:514
```

Does not work.. I tried single quotes, and double quotes.. triple escaping the spaces.. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just ended up creating a symlink to the folder, and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this in legacy mode, but it is easy in RainerScript, which your rsyslog probably supports. Replace all by

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")
input(type="imfile"
    File="/var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Logs/*"
    Tag="plex"
    Severity="info"
    Facility="local3")
local3.* @@10.0.0.5:514
```

Note that although there is a parameter `stateFile="stat-plex"`, it is deprecated and may not work well for glob files. You are supposed to let rsyslog handle the state file name itself.